# Eclipse e4 OSGI Service @Component Annotation

Tags: osgi, rcp, e4

If a create the following OSGI-INF/service.xml and set it via Service-Component: OSGi-INF/service.xml in my MANIFEXT.MF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<scr:component xmlns:scr="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/scr/v1.1.0" name="EvalManagerContextFunction">

   <implementation class="x.y.context.EvalManagerContextFunction"/>

   <property name="service.context.key" type="String" value="x.y.eval.EvalManager"/>

   <service>
      <provide interface="org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IContextFunction"/>
   </service>

</scr:component>
```

The EvalManager is created if it is requested the first time (ContextFunction Class `compute` is called)

Now if I try to do the same with annotations the `compute` Functions is not called.

```
@Component(name = "EvalManagerContextFunction", service = IContextFunction.class, property = "service.context.key=x.y.eval.EvalManager")
public class EvalManagerContextFunction extends ContextFunction {

    @Override
    public Object compute(IEclipseContext context, String contextKey) {

        EvalManager manager = ContextInjectionFactory.make(EvalManager.class, context);

        context.get(MApplication.class).getContext().set(EvalManager.class, ContextInjectionFactory.make(EvalManager.class, context));

        return manager;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any references to the `@Component` annotation class anywhere in the Eclipse core source so it would appear it is not supported.

There is a plug-in in the Eclipse Marketplace [here](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/declarative-services-annotations-support) which appears to add support for this (I have not tried this).

Update: Support for this has been added to the Eclipse Neon Milestone 6 (4.6M6) build.

Comment: Ok thank you greg. I will live with xml files for now.

Comment: I have used the DS support plugin you mention, it is working perfectly. The plugin automatically creates the XML definition file on-the-fly whenever you change your component.

Comment: I am using Neon M6 but it failed with plugin not compatible. The author of this plugin answered a question where he said it should work in Neon M6 without adding some extra plugins `Dirk, the functionality implemented by this plugin has been added directly to Eclipse PDE as of Neon M6 (to be released shortly). See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376950`

Comment: Added note about Eclipse Neon to the answer.